# Eyeshot 9 ReadAutodesk class displays DXF's TEXT entity as symbols

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, dxf, eyeshot

I'm using Eyeshot version 9 with my .NET app to display DXF files among other things. I'm having trouble with displaying TEXT entities from DXF file. All characters from TEXT entity are transformed and displayed as symbols.

I've tested same dxf file in Solidworks and few online viewers and they are displayed properly.

Line which reads dxf file:

```
var readAutodesk = new devDept.Eyeshot.Translators.ReadAutodesk(dxfPath);
```

Eyeshot's dll-s that are included in my project are :

- devDept.Eyeshot.Control.v9.dll
- devDept.Eyeshot.Control.x86.v9.dll
- devDept.Geometry.v9.dll
- devDept.Graphics.v9.dll

DXF Text entity:

```
0
TEXT
8
1 
62 
7 
10 
0.03916207
20
0
30
0
40
0.002506372
1
X Axis [m]
50
0
0
```

The output of this "X Axis [m]" is in red circle :

[image]

All other entities are displayed correct such as CIRCLE, LINE ...

Comment: The detected font is `windings` or something similar. Your file must have a custom font. You can always manually change the font of each text entities to the default

Comment: Do you know how to do it ? I've tried with Group Code 7 - Text style name, but it doesn't do any change.

Comment: My text styles are always on `Standard` and have nothing special and it always works. Can you create an empty autocad file from the default template, add a text and save it to dxf and try open that one. If it doesn't work then it might be your dll the issue. I have noticed with autocad things i need to refer to the x64 library for the control dll. I have Eyeshot 11 right now so mine is `devDept.Eyeshot.Control.x64.Win.v11` it is located here `C:\Program Files\devDept Software\Eyeshot Ultimate 11\Bin\x64\devDept.Eyeshot.Control.x64.Win.v11.dll`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you encountered a known bug.

Which version of Windows do you have on your PC? Windows 10? 
If so, the **Windows 10 update 1803** introduced a bug in Eyeshot that changes the font of the imported texts from an Autocad file.

The devDept team fixed it in Eyeshot 11 (the current one when the bug appeared) and propagated this fix also for Eyeshot 10 (the previous version).

You are using Eyeshot 9, so that is probably why you are still facing this issue.

Comment: Yes I use Win 10. Problem is solved with upgrading to Eyeshot 12.

Comment: @HarisHukić perfect! ;)